# tar/gzip excluding certain files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gzip, tar

I have a directory with many sub-directories. In some of those sub-directories I have files with `*.asc` extension and some with `*.xdr`.

I want to create a SINGLE tarball/gzip file which maintains the directory structure but excludes all files with the `*.xdr` extension.

How can I do this?

I did something like `find . -depth -name *.asc -exec gzip -r9 {} +` but this gzips every `*.asc` file individually which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to use the `--exclude` option:

`tar -zc -f test.tar.gz --exclude='*.xdr' *`

Comment: What is the syntax for multiple files? I tried *.xdr,*.pdf but failed

Comment: I did it by adding --exclude again. `--exclude='*.pdf' --exclude='*.mp4'`

Answer (score 1):

gzip will always handle files individually. If you want a bundled archive you will have to tar the files first and then gzip the result, hence you will end up with a .tar.gz file or .tgz for short.

To get a better control over what you are doing, you can first `find` the files using the command you already posted (with -print instead of the gzip command) and put them into a file, then use this file (=filelist.txt) to instruct tar with what to archive

```
tar -T filelist.txt -c -v -f myarchive.tar
```

Comment: That's fine. How can I do it with tar?

Comment: I guess something like this will work:

tar -cf src.tar --exclude='*.xdr' src